# Haskell modules: hidden names and ghci

Tags: haskell, module, ghci, name-hiding

I'm trying to export just a subset of names from a Haskell module, but ghci happily lets me access even the hidden names.

```
module Hiding (shown, calc) where

calc = shown * hidden

shown :: Int
shown = 3

hidden :: Int
hidden = 2
```

But when trying this in ghci I get:

```
Prelude> :l Hiding.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Hiding           ( Hiding.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Hiding.
*Hiding> hidden
2
```

What am I doing wrong?

(Edit: for what it's worth, I'm using ghci 6.12.3 on Arch Linux)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like GHCi is loading your module for you to inspect it, i.e. putting you in the scope of the module. Two hints at that are the prompt `*Hiding>` and the fact that you accessed the hidden function.

Edit:
End there it is: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#id3045728

Comment: Thanks, that's it. I can get around it like this: 
Prelude> :l Hiding.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Hiding           ( Hiding.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Hiding.
*Hiding> :m -Hiding
> :m +Hiding
Hiding> 
though that's quite clumsy

Comment: @oggy - ghci will only do this for interpreted modules.  If you compile Hiding.hs first, ghci can import the module from the object file and only the exported functions will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you've done the right thing. If you attempt to reference that module from another module I'll bet `hidden` refuses to work. Could be that GHCI is all-knowing :)